# Missing appengine-api-labs.jar and other required libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am moving a Google App Engine (Java) project from a PC to a Mac and I got these errors:

```
Project 'InsightAlerts' is missing required library: 'C:/MyEclipse/Common/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.6.4.v201203300216r37/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar'
Project 'InsightAlerts' is missing required library: 'C:/MyEclipse/Common/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.6.4.v201203300216r37/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar'
Project 'InsightAlerts' is missing required library: 'C:/MyEclipse/Common/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.6.4.v201203300216r37/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar'
Project 'InsightAlerts' is missing required library: 'C:/MyEclipse/Common/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.6.4.v201203300216r37/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4/lib/testing/appengine-testing.jar'
```

I'm sure I had something wrong with my configuration on the PC but how do I fix it now on my mac?

Environment:
- Mac

- iOS version 10.9.5
- Eclipse (Juno)
- BitBucket

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Mac so this is what I did to solve the problem:

- Show hidden directories: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/08/04/how-to-show-hidden-files-folders-finder-mac/.  I'm not sure this step was needed.
- In Eclipse, click the project in the package explorer.
- Right click the project, choose Build Path => Configure Build Path.
- Click the Libraries tab.
- There were 4 libraries with errors next to them, so I did the following for each one.
- Click a library that has an error and click Edit.
- On the Favorites panel on the left of the "Edit JAR" dialog box, click "Macintosh HD".
- Find the Applications directory and open up /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.12/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.12/lib/impl/ or /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.12/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.12/lib/testing/ for appengine-testing.jar.
- Click Open button.
- Click Ok button.
- At this point the four errors were gone.